# How can i catch Window taskbar closing Event in VB 6.0?

Tags: vb6

I'm just a newbie.

[image]

The problem is when I close the form from taskbar the program actually doesn't close and run in background process. But When close the program properly by clicking the close button the program does close and also in background process.
So, What I want to do is to catch the window taskbar closing event and make the program terminate completely.
I used **Visual Basic Studio 6.0**.
Any help and any advice please.
Kindly Answer my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in below links.
1). Visit [VB 6.0 system tray application doesn't close gracefully when Windows shuts down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367448/vb-6-0-system-tray-application-doesnt-close-gracefully-when-windows-shuts-down?rq=1)
Thanks a lot @Matt and @JFV.

2). Visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445536(v=vs.60).aspx
Can found the answer in above link too.

Comment: That's exactly what i need to know. It fixs my problem.